# Why does my link say unable to find file?

Tags: html, file, frontend, anchor

I am working on a project and am making an anchor tag link to another page (just another page on the website). Yet when I do this, it says, "Your file was not found". What could be wrong? Here is what my anchor tags look like

```
<a id="mission-link" class="link" href=".../Home/index.html#mission">
```

Thanks for the help and have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 3 dots instead of 2

`.../Home/index.html#mission`

should be

`../Home/index.html#mission`

If that still doesn't fix it, then we'd need to know your folder structure to know whether you should actually be moving up a directory or not. `..` moves up a directory from where the current file is.